# Wordpress register_sidebar() id argument WEIRD scenario

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

Ok so at first, when I initialized the widgets in my custom theme, the side bar was totally blank and I can't see any widgets I added from the admin panel,
Here's my first code in the `functions.php`:

```
function ourWidgetsInit() {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Sidebar',
        'id' => 'sidebar1'
    ));
}

add_action('widgets_init', 'ourWidgetsInit');
```

Now the code above wasn't working till I changed the id to another one which is `sidebar_widget` like this

```
function ourWidgetsInit() {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Sidebar',
        'id' => 'sidebar_widget'
    ));
}

add_action('widgets_init', 'ourWidgetsInit');
```

Now it worked! Very weird thing is, I did some tests and it seems that the only ID it accepts `is sidebar_widget`!! Changing the id value to others such as `sidebar1` or `sidebar_1` or many more causes the widgets on the side bar to disappear again! Any idea why this is happening? I'm pretty sure all those previous ids I entered are unique! Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Both codes are working. I see the sidebar in admin menu after adding your code in theme's functions.php